# Java - Exception as method return type and Error in throws part of declaration

Tags: java, exception, error-handling

Recently I stumbled across the following piece of code.

```
public class ErrorException {
  public Exception odd() throws Error {
      return new Exception();
  } 
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Error {
      new ErrorException().odd();
  }
}
```

My questions are as follows:

1. Why Java allows Exception in a method return type when the throws part of the declaration has been created specifically to handle exceptions ?
2. Why Error class is allowed in the throws part of method declaration when Error can never be handled by the calling method ?
3. Are there any specific scenarios where an Exception as method return type or Error in throws part of method declaration are useful ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1. Because an Exception is an Object like any other in Java. 2. This question is based on a false assumption ("Error can never be handled by calling method") 3. If you need to create a specific subclass of a custom exception based on contextual information, then yes, it might be useful to return an Exception

Comment: [`SQLException#getNextException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/SQLException.html#getNextException--) comes to mind. [`Throwable#getCause`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#getCause--) returns a `Throwable`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the comments.

Went back to https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/catch.html and found the following:

> *Each catch block is an exception handler that handles the type of exception indicated by its argument. The argument type, ExceptionType, declares the type of exception that the handler can handle and must be the name of a class that inherits from the **Throwable** class.*